# How can I get portfolio items from a category name?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a `porfolio-item.php` customized. What I'm trying to do is, for example:

If my actual portfolio-item, have the category name = `team-nub`;

I'm trying to show a list in a `div` with all the portfolio-items with the category name `team-nub` but I can't find the way, or the function to make it work.

I have this for now, but it didn't work:

```
<div>
    echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category', "Category: team-nub" ); 
</div>
```

Comment: I think we're going to need a lot more of the code sample to help you debug this. Without knowing what any of these functions do, the best I can suggest is that there is an error in one of your functions.

Comment: no, im not using any own function, Im using a function native from wordpress portfolio, and maybe what im trying to search is created already, thats why im asking that

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the wordpress tag. My bad.